# Equivalent of Oracle LISTTAGG in Excel

Tags: excel, oracle, concatenation, listagg, textjoin

I am looking to concatenate the values in MS Excel based on the keys in Col1 as shown below. This could be something equivalent of a listagg in Oracle. Kindly help as I am facing difficulty in using TEXTJOIN formula. Can someone please simplify and post the result ?

***Source Columns(Excel):***

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| key1 | 123 |
| key1 | 234 |
| key1 | 345 |
| key2 | abc |
| key2 | pqr |
| key3 | xyz |

***Expected result(Excel):***

| Col1 | Concatvalues |
| --- | --- |
| key1 | 123;246;345 |
| key2 | abc;pqr |
| key3 | xyz |

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to `LAMBDA()` function then can try below formula for one go.

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(A2:A7),y,BYROW(x,LAMBDA(z,TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,FILTER(B2:B7,A2:A7=z)))),CHOOSE({1,2},x,y))
```

[image]

Otherwise You can try `TEXTJOIN()` with `FILTER()` formula-

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,FILTER($B$2:$B$7,$A$2:$A$7=E2))
```

For `E2` cell you can use `=UNIQUE(A2:A7)` function.

[image]

Comment: I tried a sample and it worked. thanks a ton. I will apply on the full dataset and let you know for any queries. Much appreciated

Comment: Remember `TEXTJON()` has a character limitation of `50000`. So, it can't join more `50000` word.